# Написание топонимов: Остра брама либо Острая брама

Tags: топонимика

Каково правильное написание? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Википедия говорит нам так:

> О́страя бра́ма (лит. Aušros Vartai,
> польск. Ostra Brama, белор. Вострая
> Брама).     Ворота издавна назывались
> «Острыми воротами» (польск. Ostra
> Brama букв. «Острые ворота»; лит.
> Aštria broma букв. «Ворота зари»), в
> речи русских жителей иногда
> употребляется наименование «Святые
> ворота». Многочисленные попытки
> связать название с острыми шпилями
> первоначального готического вида
> ворот, с названием г. Ошмяны или с
> формой сужающейся к воротам улицы не
> убедительны. Более основательна, но
> плохо мотивирована связь с названием
> квартала — Острый конец, которое,
> однако, также трудно объяснить.
> Существует версия, объясняющая
> название квартала и ворот с родовым
> именем князя Константина Острожского.
> Литовское название лит. Aušros Vartai
> («Ворота Зари») появилось в литовских
> газетах начала XX века, в прямом
> смысле вполне бессмысленно, поскольку
> ворота обращены отнюдь не на восток,
> но внешне созвучно исконному названию
> и отвечает метафорике национального и
> духовного возрождения. Иногда ворота
> назывались Медницкими (Медининкскими),
> так как от них начинался путь к
> лежащему в 30 км Медининкскому замку.

Но в интернете можно встретить обе вариации названий. На запрос "Остра Брама" Гугл выдаёт в разы больше результатов, чем на "Острая Брама", хотя это тоже нельзя считать показателем.  
Например, боевая операция подпольной польской Армии Крайовой по освобождению Вильнюса от немцев называется на русском «О́стра бра́ма» (польск. Operacja Ostra Brama) (Википедия).    
Наверное, допустимы оба варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Посольку название не фиксируется топонимическими справочниками (если я ошибаюсь, прошу поправить), то оба написания верны. Тем более, что и у "польского", и у "литовско-белорусского" варианта есть основание в виде оригинального первоисточника.
В таких случаях вполне логично предпочесть наиболее русский вариант, если, конечно, автор не преследует цель передать национальный колорит.

Comment: "По-русски" звучит как-то странно: слово "острая" понятно, а "брама" - нет. Если же оба слова нерусские, можно догадаться, что это какое-то название.

Comment: Да, я с вами согласен, что для понимания, что это название, лучше говорить "Остра Брама", иначе может возникнуть недоразумение. Но второй вариант исключать, пока нигде не зафиксирован первый, тоже не стоит.

Comment: >По-русски" звучит как-то странно: слово "острая" понятно, а "брама" - нет.

Вы знаете, сколько таких "русских" названий? От Новой Ладоги и Старой Руссы до [Молодого Туда][1] и деревни "Большие Акияры". Даже если и по-русски, то что оно такое - никто не знает.

ЗЫ "Сельское поселение Деревня Большие Козлы" - вот это по-русски.

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%B4

Comment: Я купила подробную карту Татарстана, читала. Получила большое удовольствие!